# Column Store Index vs Ordinary Index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2014, clustered-index, columnstore

I have some tables in that two of them have around 1 million of records. In one procedure I'm using these tables, and it is taking around 5-10 minute to fetch around 25,000 rows.

I created some clustered and non clustered indexes, and the execution plan shows all are Clustered Index seek or Non-Clustered Index seek. But the procedure still takes more than 5 minute to execute.

So i tried creating Column-Store Index but still no Improvements.

Guys, can anyone give advise me on this. How i need to create Index and Which one is better Column-Store or Ordinary Clustered/non-clustered Index

Comment: What do you mean "produce"? What does the stored procedure do (select/insert) ? What is the execution plan? 5 minutes would be a *long* time for 5M rows, not 25K. Creating a columnstore index won't make a stored procedure go faster if it processes eg each row one by one in a loop or cursor

Comment: To put it simply, it's impossible to help without any clues. You need to post the stored procedure code and the execution plan at least.

Comment: The procedure have no any loop or cursor. It have some insert and select statement only. There is some issue to post the query or execution plan I will try to post  the execution plan after discussing with manager.

Comment: Are you having similar performance levels with other similar queries against tables of similar size? If so, you might just be resource constrained, probably at the storage level and perhaps even memory. As you figure out if you can share more details on your query and execution plan, look into the available and consumed resources for that SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

Whether columnstore index is a good idea depends on the purpose of the table / database is. The columnstore is designed to be used in large fact tables in data warehouses. It is not built for OLTP or any other operational database. If you're working with a data warehouse, clustered columnstore is usually a good idea, although I think it's designed for more than a million tows, but I would assume it still works ok, and you should also get benefits from improved compression.

For OLTP or mixed used, you probably want to just focus on indexing. Look at the query plan and `statistics io` output to see what's causing the slowness, and if you don't figure out what could be wrong, either edit the post or ask a new one with details about your tables, indexes and the query plan.

Typical things to look in the query plan are index scans and sorts & key lookups for a large number of rows. Since you're working with million rows, there could also be spools or spills into temp db that's causing the slowness.